# Windows WindowHandle is not Selenium driver.CurrentWindowHandle

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, handle, window-handles

im working on a Software that is using Selenium to automate some tests.

Currently i have to use a specific Browser. I thought i can use the WindowHandle, but somehow the WindowsWindow handle is another than the Selenium window handle.

With this code:

```vb
        Dim hWnd As Integer
        Dim processRunning As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()

        For Each pr In processRunning

            If Equals(pr.ProcessName, "chrome") Then
                hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()
                Form_Main.Console(pr.MainWindowHandle)
                ShowWindow(hWnd, 0)
            End If
        Next
```

I get this: 3812626

But with this Code:

```vb
   Form_Main.Console(driver.CurrentWindowHandle)
```

I get this: CDwindow-911174B9E633363263F9CD7719E67D3A

I don't know how to google properly either. Everything it shows me are some pictures of actual window handles -.-"

Is there a way to link those handles?

Comment: seems like you've got 1) a handle for the browser instance , and 2) a handle for the browser instance's tab/window.  The browser creates a new handle for each new tab/window.  For one of the browsers (I think it's Firefox?) the handle may match before a page is loaded...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No the CDwindow is sadly not changing.

Comment: I believe this is done to keep the "sandbox" intact.  You wouldn't want a local scope window handle tied to a browser window that is connected to the internet.  In (again I think it's Firefox's) case, if you load a local file the handle does not change... but once you navigate to the internet, it assigns it's own internet scope handle...